# Do homeomorphisms between open sets preserve the boundary of those sets?

Tags: general-topology

I was reading about differentiable manifolds on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold) and stumbled upon the following image, explaining transition maps.

[image]

I have a very elementary topological question about this image: Is it necessary that

$$
\partial \varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta) \cap \partial \varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha) \neq \emptyset ?
$$

In other words, could there exist a homeomorphism mapping the light blue area to the interior of $\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$?

Comment: In this very instance $\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)$ is homeomorphic $\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$.

Comment: It is not necessary that the formula holds. However, the formula does not seem to capture what you write after it. A counterexample is $U_{\alpha} = (0,1)$ and $U_{\beta} = (\frac{1}{2},2)$ and $\varphi: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ your favourite homeomorphism between the two. Then the boundary of $\varphi(U_{\alpha})$ is empty, but $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$ "touches the boundary"

Comment: @G.Chiusole yes you are right. what is a better way to formalize "touching the boundary"?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to have $U_\beta \subset U_\alpha$, from which it would follows that $U_\beta = U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$, and therefore $\phi_\alpha(U_\beta) \subset \phi_\alpha(U(\alpha)$ and $\phi_\alpha(U_\beta) = \phi_\alpha(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta)$.

Like all illustrations in mathematics, this one is designed to aid your intuition, not to be a representation of all possible examples, although perhaps it is chosen to be representative of a "typical" example.

**Added:** It could even happen that $U(\beta) \subset \overline{U(\beta)} \subset U_\alpha$ where the bar refers to "closure"; this would force $U(\beta)$ to be "in the middle of $\phi(U_\alpha)$" in some intuitive sense.

Comment: hm maybe i didn't make myself clear enough but i am specifically wondering if i can pick a light blue area of $U_\alpha$ "touching the boundary of $U_\alpha$" and map it "away from the boundary" into the interior of $\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$

Comment: I added a comment to address that point. But, there is a vagueness to your question that it is not possible for me to address, i.e. you ask whether you could "map it" away from the boundary. In the statement of your question, the data $U_\alpha$, $U_\beta$, $\phi_\alpha$, $\phi_\beta$ have all been given. By asking whether something can be mapped to something else, perhaps you are asking a question about when certain subsets of Euclidean space are diffeomorphic to other subsets, but I cannot really tell.

Comment: Certainly if these sets are all diffeomorphic to the open unit  $n$-ball in $\mathbb R^n$, which is typically the case with coordinate charts, you can use the fact that any two sets that are diffeomorhic to the open unit $n$-ball are diffeomorphic to each other.

Answer (score 0):

In a general sense, Lee Mosher answered your question. However, let me make another remark:

The illustration suggests that $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$ contains a boundary point of $U_{\alpha}$. If that is the case, then it is indeed necessary that $\partial \varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta) \cap \partial \varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha) \neq \emptyset$.

To see this, note that a homeomorphism maps interior points to interior points. Let $x \in U_{\alpha}$ be an interior point, then there is some open $V \subseteq U_{\alpha}$ s.t. $x \in V$. Then since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, it is open, and hence $\phi(x) \in \phi(V) \subseteq \phi(U_{\alpha})$ with $\phi(V)$ open which means that $\phi(x)$ is an interior point of $\phi(U_{\alpha})$.

Now notice that if some subset $A \subseteq U_{\alpha}$ contains some point $p$ which is in the boundary of $U_{\alpha}$, then it is not an interior point, and hence is not mapped to an interor point of $\phi(U_{\alpha})$. Hence $\phi(A)$ cannot lie in the interior of $\phi(U_{\alpha})$.

Comment: thank you this makes sense, but $U_\alpha$ is open and so $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ does not contain boundary points

Comment: Ah yes, so you question is when $\partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$, then whether we have $\partial \phi(A) \cap \partial \phi(B) \neq \emptyset$. This is true; let me edit my answer.

Comment: i'm wondering if, all other things being equal, the light blue area in the bottom left (say) could be drawn into the middle of $\varphi(U_\alpha)$, i.e. with green all around it.

Comment: While writing up what I though was an answer I noticed what I wrote in the comment only works for a homeo which is the restriction of a continuous map on some larger set (at least containing the closure). So I am not 100% sure anymore.